# highlight row if cell value doesn't match with another row Power BI

Tags: formatting, powerbi, conditional-statements, dax

I have 2 columns in a PowerBI table which I would like to compare and highlight if the value doesn't match.

Example -

```
ID   Column1   Column2
1      AA        AA 
2      BB        BBA
3      DD        DD
4      EE        E
```

In the output, I would like to highlight the `column 1` cell or the entire row if the value is not an exact match with `column 2`.

I have search a lot for the solution and strangely I haven't found any solution.
Can someone help me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:
First create an auxiliar column with a simple logic to detect wich rows are different.

```
NoMatch = IF( Tabl3[Column1] = Tabl3[Column2], 1, 0 )
```

Then select your visualization and go to Format --> Conditional Format.
Select the ID column, activate the background color option and select advanced options.
Go to rules and select the column NoMatch then you have to create 2 rules as the followings (My pbi version is on spanish but you will get the idea)
[image]

Repeat this process for every column you are interested.

This is the result

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Good answer and well documented!